# How to do DR from GCP to AWS for PaaS services (CloudSQL)?

Tags: amazon-web-services, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, disaster-recovery

How to do disaster recovery from GCP to AWS for PaaS services? I can do the DR from GCP VMs to AWS but what about the managed database like CloudSQL?

Comment: Why do you want a failover from GCP to AWS? That does not sound reasonable or even possible for anything other than the most generic services (like VMs).

Comment: Customer want to have a multi-cloud setup and diversify the risk.

Comment: Diversify what risk? Does the customer realize that half the internet is down if AWS fails? What services are you using? For most services a fail over is certainly impossible, not sure about cloud sql in particular.

Comment: Diversify the risk - If GCP fails, then they can move to AWS. Yeah, need to educate them, that the chance of that is less, but its their management decision to have multi-cloud presence and they wanted to test through DR. In GCP they are using GCE and MySQL CloudSQL, they have 1 more VM on ServerMania.

Comment: Can you put numbers on that "risk"? Let the customer put numbers on it, what is the business risk / impact, what is the cost of implementing DR, what money can they demand from Google if GCP fails and violates its SLAs, ... How often has GCP failed in the past years? Are you talking about GCP having an incident and temporarily being offline or GCP being shut down?

Comment: Sure, will get back to them to put the number on it. For DR, both the scenarios would be applicable - down for couple of mins as well as hypothetical situation of GCP completely shutdown for couple of days. If I propose them to do the DR on GCP itself with RPO and RTO both of 30 mins, what would be thee right solution?

Comment: Agree with @luk2302. The multi-CSP DR should cost more than the risk itself, in addition of the poor quality/high manual maintenance required to be sure that all is up and running.